# How to deploy Nestjs app on Digital Ocean?

Tags: typescript, express, deployment, nestjs, digital-ocean

I keep getting a Deploy Error:Health Checks. Everything works fine on my local with `npm run start:dev`. It's also not showing any obvious errors in the logs. Im also using a 5 dollar droplet. Im also using the builtin CICD from Digital Ocean(PaaS).

deploy logs

```sh
[2022-04-16 19:53:01] 
[2022-04-16 19:53:01] > yakkabot@0.0.1 start:prod /workspace
[2022-04-16 19:53:01] > node dist/main
[2022-04-16 19:53:01] 
[2022-04-16 19:53:02] [Nest] 17  - 04/16/2022, 7:53:02 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[2022-04-16 19:53:02] [Nest] 17  - 04/16/2022, 7:53:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +43ms
[2022-04-16 19:53:02] [Nest] 17  - 04/16/2022, 7:53:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[2022-04-16 19:53:02] [Nest] 17  - 04/16/2022, 7:53:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[2022-04-16 19:53:02] [Nest] 17  - 04/16/2022, 7:53:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] YakkaBot dependencies initialized +0ms
[2022-04-16 19:53:03] [Nest] 17  - 04/16/2022, 7:53:03 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] EthplorerController {/token-metrics}: +63ms
[2022-04-16 19:53:03] [Nest] 17  - 04/16/2022, 7:53:03 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/token-metrics/topTokenHolders/:tokenId/:limit, GET} route +2ms
[2022-04-16 19:53:03] [Nest] 17  - 04/16/2022, 7:53:03 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +3ms
[]
```

build logs

```sh
[2022-04-16 19:51:24] Adding 2/2 app layer(s)
[2022-04-16 19:51:24] Adding layer 'launcher'
[2022-04-16 19:51:25] Adding layer 'config'
[2022-04-16 19:51:25] Adding label 'io.buildpacks.lifecycle.metadata'
[2022-04-16 19:51:25] Adding label 'io.buildpacks.build.metadata'
[2022-04-16 19:51:25] Adding label 'io.buildpacks.project.metadata'
[2022-04-16 19:52:06] *** Images (sha256:f46327d2fbb45599a64b071296ea4d9e477bf7b8202192643e79e98cbbe9aee1):
[2022-04-16 19:52:06]       <image-1>
[2022-04-16 19:52:07] Reusing cache layer 'heroku/nodejs-engine:nodejs'
[2022-04-16 19:52:07] Reusing cache layer 'heroku/nodejs-engine:toolbox'
[2022-04-16 19:52:30] Reusing cache layer 'digitalocean/node:node_modules'
[2022-04-16 19:52:32] => Uploaded the built image to the container registry
[2022-04-16 19:52:32] => Build complete
[]
```

[image: Deployment Settings]

Comment: Do you have that endpoint available? k8 expects such endpoint to determine the liveness of the pod. I bet that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check again port of the server on the main file, maybe it is not 3000! The port must same with port on server and port on digital ocean

Answer (score 0):

The default http port for a nestJS application is 3333.

Answer (score -1):

on app settings change http port to 3000, the default port

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).